# Using Python Selenium - How to enter text on the web <p> tag

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am running into trouble, i am wondering how do i enter a custom text to a paragraph on a webpage.

The paragraph tag already has a default text example below [see Screenshot1]:

```
<p class="MuiTypography-root jss43 MuiTypography-body1">35 Years</p>
```

[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idvLn.png)

I want to play with this tag to write my own text here lets say "`25 Years`".

Please assist!

I tried following:

I've requisite library imported
also check that there is no iframe..

```
gender = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
    (By.CLASS_NAME, 'MuiTypography-root')))

gender.click() # this click and i can see items
gender.send_keys('25 Years')  # not working 
gender.innerHtml('25 Years')  # not working
```

Comment: what do you mean by not working when you use gender.send_keys('25 Years')? is it throwing any exception?

Comment: Yes @Sadha Nanda, you are correct Sadha. It throws exception. the tag that gender holds is a <P>element, having class Name : "MuiTypography-root".
I feel there should be something   .Innertext to hit the <p> and insert a text.

Answer (score 0):

try this element ((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="jss42"]/p') instead By.CLASS_NAME

Comment: Hi Ajaykumar,

I tried your approach: {didnt work}


gender = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="jss42"]/p')))............

gender.click() ---> this is working means a dropdown opens up.....BUT......


gender.send_keys('25 Years') ----> not working, throws error as below;

Error: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi Manish if it is giving drop down on clicking then may be we cannot add value by send_keys() method. You may have to trigger with select() method or by triggering the elements available in dropdown.
Or may that filed automatically take the age based on the date of birth provided. Due to which we are unable to add via send_keys() method.